# Numba signatures protocol

Tags: python, types, protocols, signature, numba

Despite searching Stack Overflow, and the internet as a whole, and reading several Stack Overflow questions and [numba.pydata.org](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html) pages, and learning some clues to how to tell Numba what types I want to give to and get from functions, I'm not finding the actual logic of how it works.

For example, I experimented with a function that processes a list of integers and puts out another list of integers, and while the decorator `@numba.jit(numba.int64[:](numba.int64[:]))` worked, the decorators `@numba.njit(numba.int64[:](numba.int64[:]))` and `@numba.vectorize(numba.int64[:](numba.int64[:]))` did not work.

(`njit` successfully went past the decorator and stumbled on the function itself; I'm guessing that concatenating elements to a list is not an available function in `'no python'` mode. `vectorize`, however, complains about the signature, `TypeError: 'Signature' object is not iterable`; maybe it's worried that a 1D array could include a single element without brackets, which is not an iterable?)

Is there a simple way to understand how Numba works to enough depth to anticipate how I should express the signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer for `jit` (and `njit` which is just and alias for `nopython=True`) is try to avoid writing signatures altogether - in the common cases, type inference will get you there.

Specific to your question `numba.int64[:](numba.int64[:])` is a valid signature and works for `jit`.

`numba.vectorize`- expects an iterable of signatures (error message), so your signature(s) need to be wrapped in a list.  Additional, `vectorize` creates a numpy ufunc, which is defined by scalar operations (which are then broadcast), so your signature must be of scalar types.  E.g.

```
@numba.vectorize([numba.int64(numba.int64)])
def add_one(v):
    return v + 1

add_one(np.array([4, 5, 6], dtype=np.int64))
# Out[117]: array([5, 6, 7], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Ah, so it's not asking for a signature of iterables, but an iterable of signatures!